# How do I write this using function in shell

Tags: linux, shell

How to simplify below script.

```
a="/mappings/file_prod_name.txt"; 

if [[ ${a,,} =~ 'dev' ]]; then
ENV="dev"
echo "Environment is $ENV "

elif [[ ${a,,} =~ 'test' ]]; then
ENV="test"
echo "Environment is $ENV "

elif [[ ${a,,} =~ 'prod' ]]; then
ENV="prod"
echo "Environment is $ENV "

else echo 'Please enter existing environment file'; fi
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please elaborate on what you are trying to achieve, what the issue is and what you've tried already to solve the issue. Also, consider posting relevant code snippets and have a look at [this help article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Cheers :)

Comment: BTW, `ENV` is an unfortunate choice of environment variable names, as it's meaningful to the shell itself. When you set `ENV=test`, any new child process that starts a shell will have that shell trying to open a file named `test` and execute its contents.

Comment: You can usefully lose the trailing semicolon; you can usefully remove the space before the closing double quotes. You have a fixed name `file_prod_name.txt` which means you'll get a fixed response ("Environment is prod"). What do you plan to change?  Is `a` going to be an argument to the function? You test the name; you don't test that the file exists, error message notwithstanding. The error message should be sent to standard error — that's what it is for. You could consider using just one `echo` for "Environment is …" — though the error case slightly complicates that, unless you use return.

Comment: (well, the above about ENV is true for a POSIX-y shell; when bash is not running in POSIX mode it uses `BASH_ENV` instead, but any child process that uses the `system()` call or otherwise invokes `sh` will be trying to source a file named by `ENV` should that name be exported to the environment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler version of your code  might look like the following:

```
a="/mappings/file_prod_name.txt"
ENV=
case ${a,,} in
  *dev*)  ENV=dev;;
  *test*) ENV=test;;
  *prod*) ENV=prod;;
esac

if [[ $ENV ]]; then
  echo "Environment is $ENV"
else
  echo "Please enter an environment file"
fi
```

Removing duplication can be done simply by moving content outside of the assignment; it does not require functions.